# Estou tentando descobrir o tamanho de um arquivo para download em servidor externo

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou fazendo

```
public function remote_size()
{
    $url = 'http://200.152.38.155/CNPJ/DADOS_ABERTOS_CNPJ_01.zip ';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36');

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);

    curl_close($ch);

    echo $size;
    echo $data;
}
```

Mas o que eu tenho como resposta e isso **-1HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Tue, 16 Jul 2019 13:02:28 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1**
Alguem tem ideia de algo que pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua url tem um espaço em branco no final, apenas troque para

```
$url = 'http://200.152.38.155/CNPJ/DADOS_ABERTOS_CNPJ_01.zip';
```

que funcionará.

Deixei um teste de exemplo para você: https://www.dev.ecowd.inf.br/teste/teste.php

Abs

Comment: Resolveu meu problema,nem imaginava que era uma coisa tao simples.Obrigado!!

Comment: Por nada rsrs thumbs up se possível. Abs